# how to select custom name in ConvertWorkspaceItem in TSF 2010

Tags: tfs

I have a project that has two folders , Main , archive . Main is mapped by Team Build for building ( which I could reach to by SourcesDirectory). This is mapped in build definition as "sources"
Then I have manually mapped "$/" to a different location which include Main and archive.
When I see in " Manage workspaces" I see two workspaces (1) which maps Main and (2) which maps complete project.

Now when I use activity ConvertWorkspaceItem as
direction = server to local
input "$/"
result some variable
workspace workspace

and builds it fails with "`$/project` is not mapped" as by default workspace being referenced is the one which maps to $(sources). 
is there a way I can modify ConvertWorkspaceItem to select user defied workspace ? or any other way I could get to `$/project` other then hard coding the path ?